# Javascript Form Validation - event.target.validity.valid

Tags: javascript, validation, listener, handler

New to javascript and just trying to make a simple form validation where if the user/pass is valid the box border turns green, and if invalid, it turns red (pictured) [Valid/Invalid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlmd0.png)

Here is my HTML: (Form Works, I'm guessing I'm screwing up on the listeners and Handlers)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="text" name="username" value="Username" minLength="6" maxlength="10" required>
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" name="password" value="Password" minLength="8" maxlength="15" required>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="function(changeStyle)">
</form> 

<script src="Script1.js">
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function valid() {
  var textElements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    textElements[i].addEventListener('input', function(changeStyle) {
    if (event.target.validity.valid) {
        textElements[i].style.border = "solid green 2px";
        textElements[i].style.boxShadow = "0 0 5px green";
    } else {
        textElements[i].style.border = "solid red 2px";
        textElements[i].style.boxShadow = "0 0 5px red";
    }
}, false);

}


</script>
```

Comment: Have you defined `i` elsewhere in your code? If so, can you include that code?

Comment: You should include any errors you're getting.

Comment: No, this is all of the code, and I'm not seeing any errors on my screen. Not even sure if [i] is correct either, just what I attempted to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are listening for an event that doesn't exist. There is no such event as "input" generated by the browser. You should be listening for "keyup".
2. You are acting as if you are iterating (by referencing `textElements[i].`) but you do not have an iteration loop in your code.

So what I've done is:

- wrap it all in a listener to ensure that the DOM is ready
- convert the result from your selector into an Array so that we have access to a convenient iterator method `.forEach` by using the Spread operator
- iterated over that array and added a 'keyup' listener to each item in the array. This means that everytime a key is hit and released, the listener will trigger

E.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="text" name="username" value="Username" minLength="6" maxlength="10" required>
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" name="password" value="Password" minLength="8" maxlength="15" required>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="function()">
</form> 

<script>

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var textElements = [...document.getElementsByTagName('input')];
  var listen = function(item, index) {
    item.addEventListener('keyup', function(ev){
      if (event.target.validity.valid) {
          item.style.border = "solid green 2px";
          item.style.boxShadow = "0 0 5px green";
      } else {
          item.style.border = "solid red 2px";
          item.style.boxShadow = "0 0 5px red";
      }
    })
  }
  textElements.forEach(listen);
});



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why does it not work when I put the script into an external Javascript file?

Comment: Probably your path to the file is wrong. You can test that by using `console.log` in the file. If it doesn't log then you're not reaching the file. That's a separate question btw.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your code. What is the textElement[i] for example but You can do something like this with JQuery:

```html
   

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <input id = "username" type="text" name="username"  minLength="6" maxlength="10" required>
      <br><br>
      <input id="password" type="text" name="password"  minLength="8" maxlength="15" required>
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="">
    </form>
    <script>

    $('#username, #password').on('keyup', function () {

      if($('#password').val().length < 8 ){
         $('#password').css("border-color","#FF0000")
      }else{
        $('#password').css("border-color","#00FFFF")
      }
    });
    </script>
```

Here keyup handler will respond to the keyboard actions of username and password. In the example if the password's length is smaller than 8 the border color of the input will be red otherwise it will be aqua